# Assembler read pressed key

Tags: assembly, key, pressed

```
cmp al, 13
jnz gonextstep
```

This part of code go to next step if I press ENTER (13), but I need do the same for F11 key. I tried to find number what I'm looking for and I wrote another code to find it.
My program wrote that this number is 127 but for 127 it doesn't work too.